# npm publish error - "npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - package version that is forbidden"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish

I tried to publish a new version of my package no npm and got this error:

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/yolo-coords - You cannot publish over the previously published versions: 1.0.4.
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
```

My lib is very short and the message doesn't make sense:

```
In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting a package version that is forbidden by your security policy
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I forgot to bump the `package.json` version, which was `1.0.4`:

```
{
  "name": "yolo-coords",
  "version": "1.0.6"
}
```

Comment: i have a same issue, but this solution doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

try with the command 'npm publish --access=public'

Answer (score 0):

try verifying your email address.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen, if The package name which you have mentioned in the package.json, is already owned owned by someone. Try changing the package name and publish.